# Updating low stock alert email Magento 1.9

Tags: email-templates, stock-status, alert

We have low stock inventory turned on in Magento.

It was brought to my attention that there was a misspelling but I can't seem to figure out what file to edit.

The furthest I got was this file located in

> /app/locale/en-US/template/email/giant_low_stock_notify.html

```
<!--@subject {{var store.getFrontendName()}}: Low stock product report@-->
<!--@vars
{"store url=\"\"":"Store Url",
"skin url=\"images/logo_email.gif\" _area='frontend'":"Email Logo Image",
@-->
<!--@styles
body,td { color:#2f2f2f; font:11px/1.35em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
@-->

<body style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
<div style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:20px 0 20px 0">
    <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0;">
        <!-- [ header starts here] -->
        <tr>
            <td valign="top"><a href="{{store url=""}}"><img src="{{skin url="images/logo_email.gif" _area='frontend'}}" alt="{{var store.getFrontendName()}}"  style="margin-bottom:10px;" border="0"/></a></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- [ middle starts here] -->
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <h1 style="font-size:22px; font-weight:normal; line-height:22px; margin:0 0 11px 0;"">Low stock report,</h1>
                <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0;">
                    Total low stock product(s): <strong>{{var count}}</strong>.
                </p>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{var stock_html}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#EAEAEA" align="center" style="background:#EAEAEA; text-align:center;"><center><p style="font-size:12px; margin:0;">Thank you, <strong>{{var store.getFrontendName()}}</strong></p></center></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

Then the stock_html is the file below that pulls in the product info:

> /app/code/community/Magegiant/Lowstocknotify/Model/Observer.php

Below is the code for the php file. After the `function _htmlheader()` where it lists the table of products that are low in stock, there is a `function _htmlfooter()`. I am assuming that is what I need to edit but am unsure of where that file is located.

```
<?php
/**
 * MageGiant
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the MageGiant.com license that is
 * available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://magegiant.com/license-agreement/
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade this extension to newer
 * version in the future.
 *
 * @category    MageGiant
 * @package     MageGiant_Lowstocknotify
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 MageGiant (http://magegiant.com/)
 * @license     http://magegiant.com/license-agreement/
 */

/**
 * Lowstocknotify Observer Model
 *
 * @category    MageGiant
 * @package     MageGiant_Lowstocknotify
 * @author      MageGiant Developer
 */
class Magegiant_Lowstocknotify_Model_Observer
{

protected $_count;
protected $_products;


public function trigger($name = '')
{
    $config  = Mage::getSingleton('lowstocknotify/config');
    $trigger = $config->getConfig('lowstocknotify/notify/trigger');
    if (!$trigger) return;
    $trigger = explode(',', $trigger);
    if (in_array($name, $trigger))
        $this->lowStockNotification();

    return $this;

}


public function afterProductSave()
{
    return $this->trigger('after_product_save');
}

public function afterPlaceOrder()
{
    return $this->trigger('after_place_order');
}

public function cronJob()
{
    return $this->trigger('cronjob_daily');
}


public function lowStockNotification()
{

    $lowStockProduct = Mage::getSingleton('lowstocknotify/lowstock')->getLowStockProducts();

    if (!count($lowStockProduct)) return;

    $config = Mage::getSingleton('lowstocknotify/config');
    if (!$config->isEnabled()) return;
    $template = $config->getConfig('lowstocknotify/notify/template');
    $emails   = $config->getConfig('lowstocknotify/notify/emails');
    if (empty($emails)) return;
    $name = $config->getConfig('lowstocknotify/notify/name');
    $from = $config->getConfig('lowstocknotify/notify/from');


    $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
    $translate->setTranslateInline(false);

    $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');


    $this->_count    = count($lowStockProduct);
    $this->_products = $lowStockProduct;
    if(!$this->_count) return;
    foreach (explode(',', $emails) as $_email)
        $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'backend'))
            ->sendTransactional($template,
                $from,
                trim($_email),
                $name,
                array(
                    'count'      => $this->_count,
                    'stock_html' => $this->_getLowStockHtml(),
                )
            );

    $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
    return true;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
protected function _getLowStockHtml()
{
    $html = $this->_htmlHeader();
    $i    = $this->_count;
    foreach ($this->_products as $_product) {

        $_row = '
        <tr>
            <td>' . $i . '</td>
            <td>' . $_product['id'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $_product['sku'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $_product['name'] . '</td>
            <td>' . number_format( $_product['qty'],0) . '</td>
            <td>' . $_product['low_stock_date'] . '</td>
        </tr>
        ';
        $html .= $_row;
        $i--;
    }

    $html .= $this->_htmlFooter();

    return $html;
}


protected function _htmlHeader()
{
    $html = '

        <h2>' . Mage::helper('lowstocknotify')->__('Low stock report') . '</h2>

            <p>' . Mage::helper('lowstocknotify')->__('There are %s products in low stock, here are list', $this->_count) . ':</p>

            <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 500px;">
                <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>' . Mage::helper('lowstocknotify')->__('N.') . '</td>
            <td>' . Mage::helper('lowstocknotify')->__('ID') . '</td>
            <td>' . Mage::helper('lowstocknotify')->__('SKU') . '</td>
            <td>' . Mage::helper('lowstocknotify')->__('Name') . '</td>
            <td>' . Mage::helper('lowstocknotify')->__('Qty') . '</td>
            <td>' . Mage::helper('lowstocknotify')->__('Low stock from') . '</td>
        </tr>

    ';

    return $html;
}

protected function _htmlFooter()
{
    $html = '';
    /**
     * If you want to remove powered links, please purchase Remove links package ($50) at https://magegiant.com ;
     * Send email to support@magegiant.com for more details.
     */
    return $html;
}
```

}

Below is a picture of the email. The highlighted portion is where I need to edit it.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the module email template file? Also check the admin setting if there is any text options?

Comment: @SukumarGorai I added the whole code from that Observer.php. This is part of Magento so it's not really an email template created by me. I will check to see if there are text options.

Comment: Can you check this line lowstocknotify/notify/template this means there is email template under app/locale/en_US/email/templates ... Or you can find from admin system->transaction emails

Comment: @SukumarGorai alright, updated the copy with the code. it pulls the variable stock_html which is the Observer.php file from what I can see unless that is wrong. I use dreamweaver so I was searching through the whole site for copies like "increasing up tp 75%" but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: do you still have the extension?
I had this few years ago, but now magegiant is down
can you share it to me? (i really need it now) :)

Comment: @yans I believe this was out of the box, not an extension.